Bounty on the question
I have made so many changes to the question https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/45115/how-does-the-alapin-variation-help-in-avoiding-the-massive-amount-of-theory-behi after every comment. And that is now the current version of the question. I just have one day left to award the bounty. I am waiting for an answer before the bounty closes.
This has happened earlier also. In that question also, the bounty has failed without anyone answering the question.
Here also, why is no one answering the question during the bounty period?

What's the question (here in this Meta post)?

From the Help Center, emphasis mine:

If you see a question that has not gotten a satisfactory answer, a bounty may help attract more attention and more answers.

A bounty is not a guarantee you'll get an answer. Frankly, as a potential answerer, I'm scared to write one if the question is changed so much. I mean, the Alapin variation is very different from the Najdorf ...
